# Textbox validation by jquery in Quiz Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to crete a fill in the blanks quiz sample.I have textbox and this textbox will be as blank in quiz.I want to validate this texbox value and if it is true,i will change textbox's colour as green,if not it will be red.Do u know  a jquery sample like that?I want clientside solution.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. When do you want the colour to change? I'm going to assume that you want it to happen on the `blur` event:

```
$("#yourTextboxId").blur(function() {
    if(!this.value) {
        $(this).css({backgroundColor: "red"});
    }
    else {
        $(this).css({backgroundColor: "green"});
    }
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/PtTJk/).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this -

```
$("#question").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Paris') $(this).css('background-color','green');
    else $(this).css('background-color','red');
});
```

This will do the validation on the `blur` event so the validation will fire when the textbox loses focus. You'll need to change the validation code to something that will suit your needs.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/eXSrq/